# Where do I find the package name (eg. com.android.browser, com.android.phone, com.android.contacts) of an existing Android App?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am learning how to use Espresso to validate intents. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents.html) has the following example:

```
intended(allOf(..., toPackage("com.android.browser")));
```

Where can I find the package names of other existing apps (eg. Gmail)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found at https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3086746?hl=en:

1. Go to the Google Play store page.
2. Search for your app (eg. Gmail) and go to the app page.
3. Google Play URL uses the following format:
   `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>`

Another way is to run a failing test and see what shows up.